# Is there a way to append the bookmark to a string in header using VBA for Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I addressed all your comments and modified my code as per below:

Sub HeaderFooterMacro()

```
'Delete the existing Header and Footer

ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete


Dim headerRange As Range

Set headerRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
With headerRange
        
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    .Bookmarks.Add Range:=headerRange, Name:="DocID"
    .Bookmarks.Add Range:=headerRange, Name:="UnderScore1"
    .Bookmarks.Add Range:=headerRange, Name:="DocName"
    .Bookmarks.Add Range:=headerRange, Name:="UnderScore2"
    .Bookmarks.Add Range:=headerRange, Name:="DocVersion"
    .InsertAfter Text:=vbTab & vbTab & "Page "
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Fields.Add Range:=headerRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
      "PAGE  \* Arabic "
    .End = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertAfter Text:=" of "
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Fields.Add Range:=headerRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
      "NUMPAGES"
      
End With

                                                                   

'Show the Form

VersionForm.Show
```

---

Form:
Private Sub OKBtn_Click()

```
Dim DocName, DocVersion, DocID, UnderScore1, UnderScore2 As Range

Set DocID = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DocID").Range
Set UnderScore1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("UnderScore1").Range
Set DocName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DocName").Range
Set UnderScore2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("UnderScore2").Range
Set DocVersion = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DocVersion").Range
    
DocID.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
UnderScore1.Text = "_"
DocName.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
UnderScore2.Text = "_"
DocVersion.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value

Me.Repaint
VersionForm.Hide
```

End Sub

Please find the screenshot below:

[Scrreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQnro.png)

I am still getting "DocVersion" in the beginning. But, I need it in the format:
"DocID""Underscore1"DocName"Underscore2"DocVersion.
Please help.

And many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick fix to your problem is simply to change the order of your code.

```
If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
End If

If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
    ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
End If

ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight

'Insert the Header | Top Left
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .add Range:=Selection.Range, name:="DocID"
    .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
    .ShowHidden = False
End With

'Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.TypeText text:="_DocName_V."

With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .add Range:=Selection.Range, name:="DocVersion"
    .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
    .ShowHidden = False
End With
Selection.TypeText text:=vbTab & vbTab

Selection.TypeText text:="Page "

Selection.Fields.add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, text:= _
"PAGE  \* Arabic ", PreserveFormatting:=True

Selection.TypeText text:=" of "

Selection.Fields.add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, text:= _
"NUMPAGES  ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

However your code really needs to be rewritten to avoid the use of the `Selection` object. For example:

```
Sub AddTextToHeaderRange()
  Dim headerRange As Range
  
  Set headerRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  With headerRange
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    .Bookmarks.add Range:=headerRange, name:="DocID"
    .text = "_DocName_V."
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Bookmarks.add Range:=headerRange, name:="DocVersion"
    .InsertAfter text:=vbTab & vbTab & "Page "
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Fields.add Range:=headerRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, text:= _
      "PAGE  \* Arabic "
    .End = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertAfter text:=" of "
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Fields.add Range:=headerRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, text:= _
      "NUMPAGES"
  End With
    
End Sub
```

**Edit due to revised question:**
If you are going to use the code you have posted in your revised question you only need 1 bookmark, not 5.

You would then use the following code to populate the text:

```
DocID.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value & "_" & Me.TextBox2.Value & "_" Me.TextBox3.Value
```

Comment: Many Thanks Timothy. I have now modified my code as per your suggestion.I still need your help. Please have a look at my modified question

Comment: @VikramNGaniga - that's what is known as shifting the goalposts. Please do not do it again. The edits that you have made to your question make it difficult for anyone to understand what the original question was.

Comment: yayyyy! It worked!!!! Thanks @Timothy.
Well, The comment box was not long enough to hold the modified code. Hence I had to modify my original post. But I do understand your concern.I am new to stackoverflow and I'll keep it in my mind next time :)

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not show how the page number is being inserted. My guess is that it is being set with right justification.

Is there a reason you are using a fixed docID rather than the FileName field?

You could save a header with the content you want (i.e. bookmarks and page fields) as a Header building Block or as AutoText in the template that contains your code and insert that using code more easily than constructing using code. That allows formatting that can be tricky to code.

Here is my information on how to do that:
http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock

"Recording a macro will work, to a limited extent.  Recorded macros will not work on someone else's system even if they have the same building blocks or even if they are a different user on the same computer. Recorded macros will not work if the template contains more than one building block with the same name, even if they are different types. Note that the file that comes with Word "Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" has many building blocks with the same names. You can use the Building Blocks Organizer and sort by name to see if there are multiple building blocks with the same name and in the same template.

Because of these limitations, often you will need to actually write a macro.

However, you can try recording one. The key is to use the Building Blocks Organizer to insert the Building Block when recording the macro, rather than a shortcut or another gallery/menu.

Any macro, recorded or written, should be stored in the same template that holds the building block. That way, if the macro is available, the building block is available.

- Note that the original is longer than can be posted here and contains screenshots. It includes sample macros as well.

Comment: Many thanks Charles. Yes, I am not recording the macro...I am writing a new macro as per your suggestion. I still need your help. Please have a look at my modified question

Comment: Still do not understand why you want to use vba for this rather than AutoText or a Header Building Block. Are you using bookmarks rather than simply inserting the text because you want to update them at some point. Otherwise, rather than adding bookmarks, why not insert your text.

The standard formatting of the header and footer styles contains a center tab and a right tab setting. You can use those for positioning text.

Does your userform's Underscore allow you to change the separator between parts?Otherwise, iIf you are always using an underscore, why build in this structure.